# Different layout for main category and sub category

Tags: magento, layout, categories, magento-1.9

So I have this weird problem that is bugging me for a few days now. I'm making a new theme for a magento shop, the design asks me to create a different layout for the main category page and a sub category page.

The normal way of doing this is to create or use a other layout in the backoffice (Catalog > Manage Categories > ... > Custom Design > Page Layout). However, the sub-category page keeps using the layout set in the main category. Use Parent Category Settings is off on the main category, however this option is not available in the sub category. I tried using the normal layouts to start with, main category on 1 column, sub category on 2 column, but it just keeps loading the 1 column on the sub category page. I also tried setting a default layout in a local.xml file and keeping the page layout option empty for the sub category, that doesn't work either.

Some other info, I'm using Magento 1.9 with the new RWD theme as base. Hoping someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the shop used an importer for their products. The importer forgot to import the "Use Parent Category Settings" that's why it didn't show that option within the sub categories. Because the option could not be set it was set to indeed use the parent settings thus explaining why the sub category used the layout of the root, even if you set a other layout on the sub category.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the category level in category controller view action and add custom layout handle:

```
$update->addHandle('catalog_category_inner');
```

and then update your layout xml (catalog.xml) to use this handle. For example:

```
<catalog_category_inner translate="label">
    <reference name="category.products">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/view_inner.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_inner>
```

Anyway solution depends on layouts difference you need to implement. But the idea would be the same anyway. If you need somehow to implement different layouts, use custom layout handles